# best practices for echo statement that outputs html?

Tags: php

Hi guys I have an application that allows users to post content on an empty div. I need some advice on making it scalable as I have to make sure if users are posting a lot of content the browser will not slow down or crash. I am a beginner so please put up with me. So in my code below I have an echo statement that prints out html content. I want to know how to make that function scalable in the long run? should I set the html as a variable then print it? should I encode it with JSON? please advice me as such. Thank-you

PHP Code

```html
<?php

include_once("connection.php");

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);


//You can use Inner Join to display the matched records in between the two tables


$query = "SELECT * FROM `qpost` A INNER JOIN `user` B ON A.id=B.id ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
 if($result) {
  
 } else {

  echo "bitch: " . $conn->error;
 }

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$time = time();

if( $time < $row['logged_time'] + 30) {

echo " <div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-8'>

<div id='thePost' class='panel panel-default'>
 <div class='panel-heading'>
   <h3 class='panel-title'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'> <b>{$row['username']}</b></span> &#8195&#8195 &#8195&#8195 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Posted_on: {$row['time']}      </h3> 

 </div>

 <div class='panel-body' style='word-break:break-all'>
       
  <h4>{$row['question']} </h4>
        <p> {$row['description']}</p>
       
    </div>

    <div class='panel-footer'>
     <button class='btn btn-primary'>Request Connection</button>
        <button class='btn btn-success'>Chat <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div> ";

  }//end if


}//end while

?>
```

Comment: Rather than echoing, I tend to favour entering html mode with `?> html to echo <?php`, since that gives my editor syntax highlighting

Comment: Yes, consider Erics tip and also when including variables in a string, do it like this "some text ".$variable." and some more". When closing the php tag for html (like Eric suggested) just use <?php echo $variable; ?> or short form: <?= $variable ?>. What do you mean by scalable? The div will adjust no matter how much text is inside.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to separate the data logic and data display ? if you used php MVC framework which will more convenient on your case. 
Following is a simple example.

```
//demo.html code
<?php
 include_once("connection.php");
 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
 //You can use Inner Join to display the matched records in between the two tables
$query = "SELECT * FROM `qpost` A INNER JOIN `user` B ON A.id=B.id ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result) {

} else {
   echo "bitch: " . $conn->error;
}
$time = time();
$data_result = array(); // focus on your data logic process
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($time < $row['logged_time'] + 30) {
    $data_result[] = $row;
  }
}
?>
<?php foreach($data_result as $index => $row) { ?>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
        <div id='thePost' class='panel panel-default'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                <h3 class='panel-title'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'> <b><?php echo $row['username']?></b></span>
                    &#8195&#8195 &#8195&#8195 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Posted_on: <?php echo $row['time']?>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-body' style='word-break:break-all'>
                <h4><?php echo $row['question']?></h4>
                <p> <?php echo $row['description']?></p>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-footer'>
                <button class='btn btn-primary'>Request Connection</button>
                <button class='btn btn-success'>Chat <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine what you're doing.
However as Eric has said you can exit and re-enter your PHP

You could store the html in a file, grab it using file_get_contents then use sprintf to manipulate it

In a file called "row.html"

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-8'>

<div id='thePost' class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
         <h3 class='panel-title'>
             <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>  
                <b>%s</b> <!-- username -->
             </span> &#8195&#8195 &#8195&#8195 
             <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'>
                 Posted_on: %s  <!-- time -->   
             </span> 
          </h3> 
    </div>

    <div class='panel-body' style='word-break:break-all'>

        <h4>%s</h4> <!-- question -->
        <p> %s</p>  <!-- description -->

    </div>

    <div class='panel-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Request Connection</button>
        <button class='btn btn-success'>Chat <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Then in your PHP....

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     $time = time();

     if( $time < $row['logged_time'] + 30) {
          $rowHtml = file_get_contents('row.html');
          echo sprintf($rowHtml, 
                       $row['username'], 
                       $row['time'], 
                       $row['question'], 
                       $row['description']);
     }
}

?>
```

I personally like as much abstraction as possible between my languages :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way to echo out HTML with PHP is using `Heredoc syntax` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
<?php
$name = 'MyName';

echo <<<MYHTML
<p>
My name is <b>"$name"</b>.
</p>
MYHTML;
?>
```